# c# - Read a specific line in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So I have this code here

```
int pos = richTextBox1.Find("someText", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
if (pos != -1)
{
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    string lineString = line.ToString();
    string inside = string.Format(lineString);
    MessageBox.Show(inside);
}
```

If you are not familiar all it is is finding what line specific text is on.

I want to take that line of text and read what the entire line is.

So for example, if the line is someText hfdshjslkgjhsdilg

then I would get a messagebox saying someText hfdshjslkgjhsdilg

Comment: Just a note: Make sure to understand the difference between lines and paragraphs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is LINQ solution:

```
string line = richTextBox.Lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(searchedText));
if (line != null) MessageBox.Show(line);
```

Comment: This one is my favorite.

Answer (score 3):

To make use of `RichTextBox` methods to do that, you could use `richTextBox1.Lines.ElementAt` to get your `Text`:

```
int pos = richTextBox1.Find("someText", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
if (pos != -1) {
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    string lineString = richTextBox1.Lines.ElementAt(line);
    MessageBox.Show(lineString);
}
```

The `Lines` will return you lines in the `RichTextBox` and your `int line` will tell you the index of the line you want to grab. So, you simply need to use them to grab your line by using `Lines.ElementAt(line)`

Answer (score 2):

```
int pos = richTextBox1.Find("someText", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
if (pos != -1)
{
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    int nextLineStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1);
    if (nextLine != -1)
    {
        string lineString = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(pos, nextLineStart - pos);
        MessageBox.Show(lineString);
    }
}
```